# Any Optimized Solution: To Get index of an Element in two List located at same position

Tags: java, collections

I want to get position of two elements 1 and A if they are located at same position.

E.g List one has elements {1,1,3,1,5}
    List two has elements {Q,B,Z,A,c}

output should be 3.

Below is my code it works all good I am looking if anybody has any **optimized solution then please do reply.**

or solution using **Java8**

```
public class GetIndex {   
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       List<String> one = Arrays.asList("1", "1", "3", "1", "5");
       List<String> two = Arrays.asList("Q", "B", "Z", "A", "C");
       for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) {
            if (one.get(i).equals("1") && two.get(i).equals("A")) {
            System.out.println("Index where 1 & A: " + i);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. What's your question? Are you encountering a specific error?

Comment: @ apemanzilla I am looking if is there any more optimized way of accomplishing.

Comment: Are you after an "optimized solution"? If so you might want to ask this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com or define "optimized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same but using java8 stream api:

```
IntStream.range(0, one.size()).boxed()
        .filter(i -> one.get(i).equals("1") && two.get(i).equals("A"))
        .forEach(index -> System.out.println("Index " + index));
```

To store indexes use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of `.forEach(..)`. Then the whole expression returns `List<Integer>`

Comment: @Ruslan..Thanks How to store this index in your solution as I want to use this index further

Comment: @BlueStar Updated answer. Then it will looks like: `List<Integer> indexes = IntStream....`

Answer (score 1):

Your code relies on the fact that `one` is smaller or equals in length to `two`, which may be incorrect.

You may want to improve that by using

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(one.size(), two.size()); i++) {
```

Otherwise, in terms of runtime complexity, worst case is O(N), when no such pair exist, and you won't do better than that for a single execution.

Comment: @Alexy appreciate your solution,But I am sure always my two list will be equal in size,so no worries on that part